# Stack inner anchor tag on top of nav

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag with a hamburger style css that toggles a fly-out menu. The thing I am stuck at is that I always want it to stay on top however at present the flyout menu goes over the anchor hamburger and hides it. The flyout menu has the class called nav-container any help is welcome here as I have tried to solve this for a few hours. Thanks in advance.

```
HTML - 
  <div class="container"> 
        <nav id="main-nav" class="hc-nav hc-nav-1">
             <ul>
                    <li class="Test page">
                        <a href="http://test-page.html">Test page</a>
                           <ul>
                              <li class="nav-has-sub">
                                       <a href="http://sub-testpage.html">Sub test page</a>

                                            <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="http://sub-sub-test-page.html">Sub sub test page</a>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ul>

                                    </li>

                            </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

        </nav>

            <a class="toggle">
                <span></span>
            </a>
   </div>
```

Flyout HTML -

```
<div class="nav-container" style="">
   <div class="nav-wrapper nav-wrapper-0">
      <div class="nav-content">
         <ul>
            <li class="nav-close"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="toggle toggle-open hc-nav-trigger hc-nav-1 nav-item" style="top:-25px;left:10px">
               <span></span>
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
            <li class="Test page nav-parent">
               <input type="checkbox" id="hc-nav-1-1-0" data-level="1" data-index="0" value="n83m4ogohw-gjximxnm4rq"><a href="# class="nav-item">Test page<span class="nav-next"><label for="hc-nav-1-1-0"></label></span></a>
               <div class="nav-wrapper nav-wrapper-1">
                  <div class="nav-content">
                     <h2>Test page</h2>
                     <ul style="text-indent: 40px;">
                        <li class="nav-has-sub nav-parent">
                           <input type="checkbox" id="hc-nav-1-2-0" data-level="2" data-index="0" value="vjoqryeoc9-trdi4kvf59"><a href="#" class="nav-item">level 2.1<span class="nav-next"><label for="hc-nav-1-2-0"></label></span></a>
                           <div class="nav-wrapper nav-wrapper-2">
                              <div class="nav-content">
                                 <h2>level 2.1</h2>
                                 <ul style="text-indent: 80px;">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">level 3</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">level 2.2</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
            <li class="Another top level"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Another top level</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.toggle
{ 
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    display: none;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 9980;
    width: 35px;
    min-height: 24px;
    width: auto;
    left: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-top: 0
}

.nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: transform .4s ease;
    padding-bottom: 450px;
}
```

Comment: Would need more of your layout stuff to see how it works currently, but you do have `position` and `top` declared twice wherein `relative` will override your `absolute` and `auto` would override your first declaration of `20px`. Judging by the syntax discrepancies it might be easier if you just give a rough visual of what you want to accomplish and folks can show you how to accomplish it more correctly.

Comment: the nav-container class isn't even in any of the html you posted

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have edited the post and have included the HTML for the flyout menu.

Comment: You need to start with a minimal, runnable example that demonstrates the problem. Can please you strip out the unused classes and get down to a single chunk of html and a little bit of css that runs and explain the problem.

Comment: I forgot to say I am using this plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Multi-Level-Sidebar-Menu-HC-MobileNav.html

Answer (score 0):

It was a very simple case of giving the class .nav-container a z-index:0

Thanks everyone for posting.